# Cannot select folders as directories using JFileChooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I am currently trying to use JFileChooser to return the path of a file or directory as a string. However, I found that I cannot choose a folder as my selection until I choose a file first. While this isn't a major issue it is by far frustrating to solve.

Gfycat of what is happening: https://gfycat.com/DeadlyDeliriousAzurevase

Code:

```
public static String openFileChooser()
{
    int returnValue = fileChoose.showOpenDialog(null);
    if(returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        fileChoose.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        return (fileChoose.getSelectedFile().getAbsoluteFile().toString());
    }
    else
    {
        return "null";
    }

}
```

Help would be absolutely appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the file selection mode **after** you've shown the dialog and the user has clicked the button. It won't have any effect at that point. You need to set it **before** you show the file chooser dialog.

The line you need to move up to be the first line in your method is:

```
fileChoose.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
```

Comment: That makes so much sense. I'm currently applying my face firmly to the desk. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    System.out.println(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsoluteFile().toString());
} else {
    System.out.println("Empty");
}
```

make sure invoke
`fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);`
before you open your dialog